# Displaying text files in website

Tags: database, text, web, content-management-system

I am developing a website for my dept. My website lists out all project papers in our college. All project papers are .txt files or pdf files or word files.

1. What is the best way of displaying?
2. Is using CMS, the efficient way to display the text content?
3. Uploading the text in DB is a big process. Need to take care of each line.
4. Is any other way of displaying it?

I dont want to change the format of txt files. It should be displayed as it is in files. Please suggest me.

Comment: This kind of question is too vague for this site. Questions should be about specific things rather than canvassing opinions.

Answer (score 0):

If it was just text files you could use a CMS as they can keep the text layout, but with Word and PDF files you could just treat it as files.

To start simply, upload the files and have an index page which links to the all the files.  To display text and PDF files it should show ok in the browser, but the Word documents would probably be downloaded and viewed on the clients PC (though there are probably plugins if you search)